# exectute user determined number of nested loops python

Tags: python

I need to execute a specific number of nested for loops. What do I mean? This is the code I used so far

```
question=input('How many for loops do you want? ') #input is 3
for item in list1:
#some code...
 for item2 in list2:
 #some code...
  for item3 in list3:
  #some code...
#the input is 3 so 3 for loops. How can I execute a specific number of for loops?
```

Comment: you're headed the wrong way, what do you really want to do?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to see what you are trying to achieve, but sometimes you may want to do something like follows, using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?#itertools.product) to have direct access to the innermost loop of your example.

```py
In [1]: from itertools import product
   ...: lists = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7, 8])

In [2]: n = int(input(f"How many lists to use ? (<{len(lists)}): "))
   ...: for items in product(*lists[:n]):
   ...:     print(items)
   ...:
How many lists to use ? (<4): 2
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(3, 4)
(3, 5)

In [3]: n = int(input(f"How many lists to use ? (<{len(lists)}): "))
   ...: for items in product(*lists[:n]):
   ...:     print(items)
   ...:
How many lists to use ? (<4): 3
(1, 4, 6)
(1, 5, 6)
(2, 4, 6)
(2, 5, 6)
(3, 4, 6)
(3, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment saying you're headed in the wrong way. I'd say, generate the lists first, and apply functions to them later.

However, the simplest option, in my opinion, is using recursion and a global list.

```py
lists = [list1, list2, list3, ...]
number_of_loops = 3


def execute_loop(number_of_loops, loop_index=0):
    # Recursion termination condition
    if loop_index == number_of_loops:
        return

    current_list = lists[loop_index]
    for item in current_list:
        #some code...
        execute_loop(number_of_loops, loop_index + 1)


execute_loop(number_of_loops)
```

Now, a few assumptions in my answer

- This will fail if you run out of lists. Add some error handling.
- Eventually using globals will bite you, so move it into a function argument.
- Python has a max recursion depth of 1000, so it works with `number_of_loops < 1000`